# Jquery how to select a tag value?

Tags: jquery

Given this:

```
<div id="ddstates1" class="bfh-selectbox bfh-states" data-state="ALG" data-country="countries_states1">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenState" value="ALG">
    <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
        <span class="bfh-selectbox-option bfh-selectbox-medium" data-option=""></span>
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
        <div role="listbox">
            <ul role="option">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option=""></a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ADE">Ain Defla</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ADR">Adrar</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ALG">Alger</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ANN">Annaba</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ATE">Ain Temouchent</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BAT">Batna</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BBA">Bordj Bou Arreridj</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BEC">Bechar</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BEJ">Bejaia</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BIS">Biskra</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BLI">Blida</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BMD">Boumerdes</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="BOA">Bouira</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="CHL">Chlef</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="CON">Constantine</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="DJE">Djelfa</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="EBA">El Bayadh</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="EOU">El Oued</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ETA">El Tarf</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="GHA">Ghardaia</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="GUE">Guelma</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ILL">Illizi</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="JIJ">Jijel</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="KHE">Khenchela</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="LAG">Laghouat</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="MED">Medea</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="MIL">Mila</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="MOS">Mostaganem</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="MSI">M'Sila</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="MUA">Muaskar</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="NAA">Naama</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="OEB">Oum el-Bouaghi</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="ORA">Oran</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="OUA">Ouargla</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="REL">Relizane</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="SAH">Souk Ahras</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="SAI">Saida</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="SBA">Sidi Bel Abbes</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="SET">Setif</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="SKI">Skikda</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TAM">Tamanghasset</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TEB">Tebessa</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TIA">Tiaret</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TIN">Tindouf</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TIP">Tipaza</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TIS">Tissemsilt</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TLE">Tlemcen</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-option="TOU">Tizi Ouzou</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want to find the value of the a tag whose data-option =="ALG".

```
$("#ddstates1 .bfh-selectbox-options")
```

has length of 1.

```
$("#ddstates1 .bfh-selectbox-options div ul")
```

has length of 1 but

```
$("#ddstates1 .bfh-selectbox-options div ul li")
```

has length of 0??

I thought

```
$("#ddstates1").find("a[data-option='ALG']").text();
```

should work as well but that fails too.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4GNDP/ -- so there must be something else wrong with your code.

Comment: What exactly does, "[it] fails" mean - what errors are you seeing in the console?

Comment: Your last example works as ahren shows. If for some reason it fails for you then you must have other HTML or JavaScript causing the issue. Perhaps duplicate IDs?

Comment: "[it] fails" means "it fails to find anything"? i.e. length of 0. [it] being the selector a[data-option='ALG']

Comment: @rism - clearly [it] doesn't, as we have shown you. So there must be something else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

this selects all tags that have data-option=ALG

```
$('[data-option=ALG]').val();
```

or to limit it to a container

```
$("#ddstates1").find('[data-option=ALG']).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/ML4tq/

this above code is working fine for me.

```
$("#ddstates1").find("a[data-option='ALG']").text();
```

Comment: Is it different from OP's answer? Should be a comment.

Comment: @j08691 - He said "but that fails too."

Comment: So then how does your reposting it help?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$('*[data-option =="ALG"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Long way:

```
console.log(
$("div#ddstates1.bfh-selectbox.bfh-states div.bfh-selectbox-options div ul li a[data-option=ALG]").text();
  );
```

Short way:

```
console.log(
$("a[data-option=ALG]").text();
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

> $('[data-option="ALG"]').text()

Comment: Needed to do this within $(window).load(function ()